# Adding a row to an Excel table in VBA recalculates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have some VBA code that is taking forever to run. I think I've isolated the problem to adding rows to a table using 'loTable.ListRows.Add'. It seems like excel is recalculating every time I add a row to the table, even with `Application.Calculation = xlManual` set.

Can someone confirm this behavior, or tell me how to confirm it?

Here is some trimmed down code showing what I'm doing:

```
Public Sub Table_ReplaceByColumn(ByVal loTable As ListObject, ByVal vHeaders As Variant, ByVal vData As Variant)
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    ' Clear the table if there is data in it
    If Not loTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete   ' Delete all rows in the table, but keep default data
    End If
    
    ' Using the headers, check for a match then update the table
    For lCounterA = LBound(vHeaders) To UBound(vHeaders)
        lNewRowCount = UBound(vData, 2) - LBound(vData, 2) + 1
        
        Do While loTable.ListRows.Count < lNewRowCount ' Add rows until table is the correct length
            ' This is the part that takes forever!
            loTable.ListRows.Add
        Loop
        
        Set rThisRange = loTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Item(2, loTable.ListColumns.[_Default](vHeaders(lCounterA)).Index)    ' Get the first row of the column
        Set rThisRange = rThisRange.Resize(lNewRowCount, 1)                      ' Expand range to fit new data
        
        vThisData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vData, lCounterA + 1, 0)) ' Get correct column of data and arrange if to directly paste
        rThisRange.Value = vThisData    ' Paste the data in the column.
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: With just this procedure, for me is not easy to tell why your code is being slow. Can you share a dummy file or post images with the ``loTable ``, ``vHeaders``, ``vData``? Do you have other worksheets with formulas that might be the cause of being slow when the rows are added?

Comment: See what a [mcve] is and try to provide one with example data how to reproduce the issue. It is unclear how you used that code.

Comment: With Calculation set to `xlCalculationManual` (note that's not what you're using but it has the same underlying value) I'm not seeing any calculation when adding rows to a list which has a formula-based column.

Comment: Consider using [`ListObject.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.resize) instead of adding listrows in a loop.

Comment: Similar Q: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/best-way-to-insert-data-into-table.631643/

Comment: I'm using this code to update several small tables, and a medium sized table. The code hangs for about a minute on the medium sized table (about 100 rows). When I interrupt the code, it always stops on the loop. I'll see if I can share an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like @BigBen was correct that adding rows with `loTable.ListRows.Add` is what's slowing it down.

Changing out the following code makes the subroutine almost instantaneous compared to about 30 seconds for 600 rows on a minimum working example.

Original Code:

```
Do While loTable.ListRows.Count < lNewRowCount ' Add rows until table is the correct length
    loTable.ListRows.Add
Loop
```

Replacement code:

```
If loTable.ListRows.Count < lNewRowCount Then ' Add rows until table is the correct length
    loTable.Resize loTable.Range.Resize(lNewRowCount + 1, loTable.HeaderRowRange.Count)
End If
```

If anyone is interested, here is a minimum working example:

[image: Minimum Working Example]

```
Sub Test()
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim vHeaderArray As Variant
    Dim vDataArray As Variant
    
    ' Get test data
    Set loTable = Table_Get("Table_1")
    
    ' Get header data
    vHeaderArray = Make_HeaderArray(loTable)
    
    ' Get body data
    vDataArray = Make_DataArray(loTable)
    
    ' Get table to update
    Set loTable = Table_Get("Table_2")
    
    ' Output to table
    'Table_ReplaceByColumn loTable, vHeaderArray, vDataArray
    Table_ReplaceByColumnFast loTable, vHeaderArray, vDataArray
    
End Sub

Public Function Make_HeaderArray(ByVal loTable As ListObject) As Variant
    Dim vHeaderArray As Variant
    Dim lIndex As Long
    ' Build an array of headers
    ReDim vHeaderArray(1 To loTable.HeaderRowRange.Count)
    For lIndex = LBound(vHeaderArray) To UBound(vHeaderArray)
        vHeaderArray(lIndex) = loTable.HeaderRowRange(lIndex).Value2
    Next
    
    Make_HeaderArray = vHeaderArray
End Function

Public Function Make_DataArray(ByVal loTable As ListObject) As Variant
    Dim vBodyArray As Variant
    Dim lIndexRow As Long
    Dim lIndexCol As Long
    Dim this_loRow As ListRow
    'Dim this_sHeader As String
    
    ' Build an array of body data
    ReDim vBodyArray(1 To loTable.ListColumns.Count, 1 To loTable.ListRows.Count)
    For lIndexRow = 1 To loTable.ListRows.Count
        'Set this_loRow = loTable.ListRows(lIndexRow).DataBodyRange
        For lIndexCol = 1 To loTable.ListColumns.Count
            'this_sHeader = vHeaderArray(lIndexCol)
            vBodyArray(lIndexCol, lIndexRow) = loTable.DataBodyRange(lIndexRow, lIndexCol).Value2
        Next
    Next
    
    Make_DataArray = vBodyArray
End Function

Public Sub Table_ReplaceByColumn(ByVal loTable As ListObject, ByVal vHeaderArray As Variant, ByVal vDataArray As Variant)
    Dim lCounterA As Long
    Dim lNewRowCount As Long
    Dim rThisRange As Range
    Dim this_vData As Variant
    
    ' Clear the table if there is data in it
    If Not loTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete   ' Delete all rows in the table, but keep default data
    End If
    
    ' Using the headers, check for a match then update the table
    For lCounterA = LBound(vHeaderArray) To UBound(vHeaderArray)
        If Table_HeaderExists(loTable.Name, vHeaderArray(lCounterA)) Then ' Does the header exist?
            lNewRowCount = UBound(vDataArray, 2) - LBound(vDataArray, 2) + 1
            
            Do While loTable.ListRows.Count < lNewRowCount ' Add rows until table is the correct length
                loTable.ListRows.Add
            Loop
            
            Set rThisRange = loTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Item(2, loTable.ListColumns.[_Default](vHeaderArray(lCounterA)).Index)    ' Get the first row of the column
            Set rThisRange = rThisRange.Resize(lNewRowCount, 1)                      ' Expand range to fit new data
            
            this_vData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vDataArray, lCounterA, 0)) ' Get correct column of data and arrange if to directly paste
            rThisRange.Value = this_vData    ' Paste the data in the column.
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub Table_ReplaceByColumnFast(ByVal loTable As ListObject, ByVal vHeaderArray As Variant, ByVal vDataArray As Variant)
    Dim lCounterA As Long
    Dim lNewRowCount As Long
    Dim this_rRange As Range
    Dim new_rRange As Range
    Dim this_vData As Variant
    
    ' Clear the table if there is data in it
    If Not loTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete   ' Delete all rows in the table, but keep default data
    End If
    
    ' Using the headers, check for a match then update the table
    For lCounterA = LBound(vHeaderArray) To UBound(vHeaderArray)
        If Table_HeaderExists(loTable.Name, vHeaderArray(lCounterA)) Then ' Does the header exist?
            lNewRowCount = UBound(vDataArray, 2) - LBound(vDataArray, 2) + 1
            
            If loTable.ListRows.Count < lNewRowCount Then ' Add rows until table is the correct length
                loTable.Resize loTable.Range.Resize(lNewRowCount + 1, loTable.HeaderRowRange.Count)
            End If
            
            Set this_rRange = loTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Item(2, loTable.ListColumns.[_Default](vHeaderArray(lCounterA)).Index)    ' Get the first row of the column
            Set this_rRange = this_rRange.Resize(lNewRowCount, 1)                      ' Expand range to fit new data
            
            this_vData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(vDataArray, lCounterA, 0)) ' Get correct column of data and arrange if to directly paste
            this_rRange.Value = this_vData    ' Paste the data in the column.
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Function Table_Get(ByVal sTableName As String) As Object
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim oSheet As Object
    
    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  ' Search through all sheets in workbook for the table
        For Each loTable In oSheet.ListObjects  ' Search through all tables in sheet for the table
            If loTable.Name = sTableName Then   ' Check this list objects name to see if it's correct
                GoTo EndFor
            End If
        Next loTable
    Next oSheet
    
    ' If we got this far, the table wasn't found.
    Set Table_Get = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
EndFor:
    Set Table_Get = loTable

End Function

Public Function Table_HeaderExists(ByVal sTableName As String, ByVal sHeaderName As String) As Boolean
Dim loHeader As ListColumn
Dim loTable As ListObject

On Error GoTo DoesNotExist
  Set loTable = Table_Get(sTableName)
  Set loHeader = loTable.ListColumns(sHeaderName)
On Error GoTo 0

Table_HeaderExists = True

Exit Function

'Error Handler
DoesNotExist:
  Err.Clear
  Table_HeaderExists = False

End Function
```